# actionscrit-3 replace "\"with ""

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, edit

Ok so i have this source from a SWF FIle and i really dont understant this programing language

```
 public function linkMe() : String {
         var _loc1_:String = this.loaderInfo.url.split("?")[0];
         if(_loc1_.indexOf("file://")<0)
         {
            _loc2_=_loc1_.split("/");
            _loc2_.pop();
            _loc3_=_loc2_.join("/")+"/";
            return _loc3_;
         }
         return "";
```

the problem is that                 return *loc3*; is returning with many \ and i get something like this URL not found `file:\//www\.xxx\.....`
the idea is that because  of `\` i get eror .. file not found 
can somene help me with a function that will replace `"\"` from `_loc3_` with `""`
with php is much easier:)

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine

```
        var s:String = "file:\\//www\\.xxx\\."; 
        trace(s)
        var s2:String = s.split("\\").join("");
        trace(s2);
```

It outputs

```
file:\//www\.xxx\.
file://www.xxx.
```

In as3 backslash (\) is an escape character. That's why "\\" in source code is actually a "\". And also "\." in source code is just "."

This code

```
        trace("\.")
```

outputs

```
.
```